# How hard is the DLP in that simple group?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, group-theory

Let $p=4q-1$ be a prime with $q$ an odd prime. Let $G=\{0,1,\dots,p-1,\infty\}$. The following law $*$ makes $(G,*)$ a commutative group of order $4q$ with neutral element $\infty$:
$$a*b=\begin{cases}
a&\text{if }b=\infty\\
b&\text{if }a=\infty\\
\infty&\text{if }a\ne\infty\text{ and }b\ne\infty\text{ and }a+b\equiv 0\pmod p\\
{ab-1\over a+b}\bmod p&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
The inverse of $a$ for law $*$ is $p-a$, with the exceptions of $0$ and $\infty$ which are their own inverse. Proof of associativity requires care, and uses $p\equiv3\bmod4$ at some point.

Computation can be simplified by keeping an element of $G$ as an integer fraction $x\over y$ with $x$ and $y$ integers modulo $p$, and the neutral element $\infty$ represented as $x\over0$ with $x\not\equiv0\pmod p$. The group law becomes, without any special case:
$${x_a\over y_a}*{x_b\over y_b}={(x_ax_b-y_ay_b)\bmod p\over(x_ay_b+y_ax_b)\bmod p}$$
and we need only 4 multiplications, 1 addition, 1 subtraction, and 2 modular reductions for $a*b$; down to 2 squarings, 1 multiplication, 1 doubling, 1 subtraction, and 2 modular reductions for $a*a$.

Since we have a group law, we can define exponentiation. Exponents can be reduced modulo $4q$, the order of the group.

Let $g$ be an element of order $q$. It can be found heuristically, perhaps starting from $g=2$ incrementally and checking $g^4\ne\infty$ and $g^q=\infty$ (Poncho's [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/45164/555#comment103049_45164) gives a faster way when we don't care that $g$ is large).

**Question**: How hard is the Discrete Logarithm Problem in the cyclic subgroup of prime order $q$ generated by $g$? Is it somewhat related to a well known group?

---

Update: The formulas $x_{a*b}=(x_ax_b-y_ay_b)\bmod p$ and $y_{a*b}=(x_ay_b+y_ax_b)\bmod p$ are the same as for complex multiplication in cartesian coordinates, except they are for integers modulo $p$. Now associativity is less surprising.

By going thru polar coordinates, we can express of $g^k$ for law $*$ without iteration: that's $((y^{-1}\bmod p)x)\bmod p$ for $x=(g^2+1)^{k/2}\cos(k\cot^{-1}g)$ and $y=(g^2+1)^{k/2}\sin(k\cot^{-1}g)$. Quantities  $x$ and $y$ are integers even though intermediate values use reals. This is computationally impractical, because we need so extreme precision. And it does not lead to a trivial way to solve the DLP.

Comment: How sure are you that this is a group? You are essentially doing Montgomery-curve $x$-only arithmetic in a strange way. I find it hard to believe this thing is associative.

Comment: @CurveEnthusiast: Yes I'm reasonably sure this is a commutative group. Associativity is indeed tricky, but does work. Basic algebra is enough to show that $(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)$ when there is no special case. A tricky case is when $a*b=\infty$ but $b*c\ne\infty$, where we need that there is no square root of $-1$ modulo $p$. But that works. I also checked my results numerically with small examples.

Comment: Actually, you can find a generator of the subgroup easier by selecting an arbitrary value $h$, computing $g = h^4$; if that's not INF, that's your generator...

Comment: Is there any other reason for $p = 4q - 1$ other than $-1$ must have no square roots? Because you could use prime $q$, arbitrary $k > 1, p = kq+1$ with $p=3 \mod 4$.

Comment: @tylo: Any prime $p\equiv3\pmod4$ makes $G$ a group. $p=4q-1$ seems to allow the smallest $p$ for a given $q$ order of the prime subgroup , and is kept from my original source. BTW, that's a proposed post-quantum asymmetric cryptosystem, found on sci.crypt `Message-ID: <ob5p8q$4dr$1@gioia.aioe.org>`. It is neatly described thus falsifiable, and based on a non-commutative and non-associative law with property $(a\star b)\star(c\star d)=(a\star c)\star(b\star d)$; a little analysis showed that it was a variant within sign of the present $*$, and that led to a total break (not requiring the DLP).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That group embeds in ​ $F_{\hspace{-0.02 in}p}[i\hspace{.02 in}]$[$^{\hspace{.02 in}*}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group) ​ via the [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) given by

$f(x) = \dfrac{x+i}{x-i}$ ​ (and ​ $\hspace{.04 in}f(\infty) = 1$ ), ​ and that embedding has a [left-inverse](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeftInverse.html)

(that is not injective and is not necessarily a homomorphism) which is the

Möbius transformation given by $\;\;\; g(z) \: = \: \dfrac{z+1}{z-1} \cdot i \;\;\;$ (and ​ $g(1) = \infty$ ).

Their partial-inverse-ness can be used to find the range of that embedding

(namely, that range is the set of fixed-points of that embedding composed with $g$);

solving reveals that it's exactly the points $z$ such that $g(z)$ is in the embedding's domain.

Further solving then gives that for all elements $c$ and $d$ of $F_{\hspace{-0.02 in}p}$,

$g(c\hspace{-0.03 in}+\hspace{-0.03 in}(d\hspace{-0.06 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.05 in}i\hspace{.02 in}))$ ​ is in that embedding's domain if and only if $\;\;\; c^{\hspace{.02 in}2}\hspace{-0.04 in}+d^{\hspace{.02 in}2} \: = \: 1 \;\;\;$.

Therefore your group is efficiently-equivalent to the mod-p [circle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group).

The latter is an efficiently-decidable subgroup of the multiplicative group of an efficient field,

and that efficient field is a simple quotient of [the Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer),

which is a [Unique Factorization Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) whose number of [units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)) is small.

Thus, by trying to find the discrete log of *both* inputs in the subgroup with

respect to the same generator of *the whole multiplicative group*, one should be

able to attack the subgroup's Discrete Logarithm Problem with [index calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm),

using $i$ and non-[associate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_(ring_theory)#Definition) G[aussian primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#As_a_principal_ideal_domain) as the factor base.

For that reason, although I don't know how [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) works, I'd imagine the hardness of

your group's DLP is *at most* not much more than for the standard DLP mod primes.

I'm not aware of any faster-than-[SNFS](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/961.pdf) DLP algorithms for *any*

[subgroups whose order has a large prime factor] of multiplicative groups of an efficient field, so in particular, I'm also not aware of any such algorithms for your group.

On the other hand, I also don't know how SNFS works.

Comment: No, it's that I found an isomorphism, efficiently-computable exactly in both ways, $\hspace{1.21 in}$ to the (mod-p) circle group itself. ​ ​

Comment: Nice answer! Milne touches on this group in his notes (http://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/ectext5.pdf) in chapter II.3.

Comment: Can you do something similar with f(a,b)=(ab+1)/(a+b)? I'll ask another day if required. The difference is the + sign instead of -.

Comment: @fgrieu : ​ ​ ​ I just fixed a typo that might have been confusing you. ​ The _mod-p circle group_ is obtained by running the rest of the circle group's definition mod-p rather than over the reals. ​ (So, the subset of $x+iy \in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[i]$ with $x^2+y^2 = 1$, which forms a group under field multiplication.) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: So the big picture is: the question's $G$ is efficiently isomorphic to  the mop-p circle group. The DLP in both is equivalent. That should thus be amenable to a small variant of index calculus (much like index calculus applies to supersingular Elliptic Curves), and perhaps to some variants of NFS. Thus the DLP in $G$ should not be much harder than the well-studied DLP in $\mathbb Z_p$; we do not have a proof that it's not even easier.

Comment: @fgrieu : ​ Yes; that's the big picture. ​ ​ ​ ​